# How to set active class dynamically on foreach element laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-9, livewires

I want to set an `active` class when I clicked it on foreach element, I have this code but it makes all looping elements active, I just want to set an active class when I click on element I clicked, like the nav menu active but this case is in foreach element,

sorry my english is bad

here is my code

```
 <div class="border-0 border-r border-slate-800 pr-2">
     <h3 class="font-semibold">Kategori</h3>
     <div class="mt-6 space-y-6 text-slate-500">
          <a href="{{ route('shop') }}" class="{{ Route::is('shop') ? 'active' : '' }} kategori-link">
             All Product
          </a>

          @foreach ($ctg as $c)
              <a href="{{ route('shop.category', $c->slug) }}"
                 class="{{ Route::is('shop.category', $c->slug) ? 'active' : '' }} kategori-link">
                 {{ $c->name }}
              </a>
          @endforeach

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not clear about you issue clearly.But what about this.
                 class="<?php if(Route::currentRouteName() == "shop.category".$c->slug){ echo 'active';} ?>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
class="{{ Route::is('shop.category', $c->slug) ? 'active' : '' }} kategori-link"
```

If you use this, you can activate the category on the **active** page:

```
@class([
    'kategori-link',
    'active' => route('shop.category', $c->slug) == request()->url()
])
```

Add it like an attribute.

Comment: Just a small performance update, move the `request()->url()` outside of the loop and use a variable like `$url` instead, e.g. outside of foreach `$url = request()->url()`, inside of foreach `'active' => route('shop.category', $c->slug) === $url.`